# For what is Microsoft app ID and password used for?

Tags: azure, deployment, botframework, bots

I am trying to deploy my Azure Bot Service but I am kinda struggling to understand for what is Microsoft app ID and password used for? Can someone explain me these terms?

I was trying to find the answers online but unsuccessfully.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the identity of the Bot Service.

You will notice in the **App registrations** of Azure Active Directory (AAD) that your Bot Service is in there.  This is to give you the ability to Authenticate, Authorize and Audit (AAA) the Bot Service.

For example, you may want to provide access for your Bot Service to other services in your subscription, or other subscriptions also using the same AAD. 
 And so, the app has a set of credentials which it can use.  The concept is similar to Managed Service Accounts in Windows Server.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "you may want to provide access for your Bot Service to other services in your subscription, or other subscriptions also using the same AAD"? From the docs I have read that for example when I want to use QnA Maker service I need to send the request with some tokens etc (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-dispatch?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=cs). But they have not mentioned that I need to grant access to my Bot for QnA Maker service to AAD and let AAD handle authorization.

Comment: Sure. If you have users accessing your Bot Service using their Azure Logins the Bot Service will need access to Azure AD to authenticate them.  By having this identity it will be able to access AAD to perform this auth. This is explained here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp%2Cbot-oauth

Comment: Thank you, I think I kinda understand it now :)

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft app ID and Password are used to register the bot with the Azure Bot Service.

After you register it, those credentials will be used by the bot connector to authenticate the calls to your Bot's service and allow you to configure the bot with the different available channels.

> Bot security is configured by the Microsoft App ID and Microsoft App Password that you obtain when you register your bot with the Bot Framework. These values are typically specified within the bot's configuration file and used to retrieve access tokens from the Microsoft Account service.

Comment: Yes, the bot will authenticate to Azure AD using the credentials, so it logs on as an app.  Think of a user logging on to a computer or domain.  They have an identity, and permissions, and attributes etc.

Comment: Do you know if bot registration with Azure Bot Service is required in order to implement authentication?