# Why does a Microsoft Bot Framework bot require an Azure AD app ID and secret?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, botframework

When creating a new Azure Web App Bot (or its successor "Azure Bot Resource") a new Azure AD App registration is either auto-created or a manually created one can be assigned.

Why exactly is this necessary? I cannot see any permissions being added or anything else that would explain this registration.

What leaves me even more puzzled: the app ID and secret end up in the `appsettings.json` file as `MicrosoftAppId` and `MicrosoftAppPassword` but they don't seem to be read anywhere.
Furthermore, when running the bot locally in Bot Framework Emulator, the input fields for "App ID" and "Secret" are labeled as optional. If ID and secret are emitted, the bot won't work. If, however, the respective entries in `appsettings.json` are removed, the emulator is happy and the bot works.

How can this behaviour be explained?

Comment: Have a look at this doc, i think it is kind of what you're looking for: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication-basics?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For what is Microsoft app ID and password used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58486730/for-what-is-microsoft-app-id-and-password-used-for).  Also Azure App registrations, This will help to configure authentication and authorization workflows for a variety of different client types. So the unique "Client ID" and "Tenant ID" we will use for the authentication and authorization in the azure ad.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @ Thomas and @Rajesh Menoth for sharing the reference links and your inputs

Bot security is configured by the Microsoft App ID and Microsoft App Password that you obtain when you register your bot with the Bot Framework. These values are typically specified within the bot's configuration file and used to retrieve access tokens from the Microsoft Account service.

Your bot does not need to manage authentication tokens because Azure does it for you using OAuth 2.0 to generate a token based on each user's credentials. Your bot uses the token generated by Azure to access those resources. In this way, the user does not have to provide ID and password to the bot to access a secured resource but only to a trusted identity provider.

**If you want to find your bot's AppID and AppPassword for an already deployed bot**

Get Azure bot resource app Id

Go to the Azure portal.

Select the Azure bot resource to obtain its app Id.

In the left pane, in the Settings section, select Configuration.

Copy and save the value contained in the Microsoft App ID box.

**Get Azure bot resource password from Azure Key Vault**

When Azure creates the Azure Bot resource, it stores the app password in Azure Key Vault. For information on how to access the key vault to obtain your password,

Reference doc [Manage a bot - Bot Service | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-manage-overview?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#microsoftappid-and-microsoftapppassword)

Comment: That link does not mention key vault